# Github API return encoded characters

Tags: python, github, ansible, jinja2, github-api

Using Ansible I query github API to retrieve comments from a Github Pull Request. It returns something like:

\\u3053\\u306e\\u30aa

Because the content is in Japanese.

Is there a way to ask Github to return non-encoded characters?
If not, is there a way in Ansible/Jinja2 or in Python to easily decode that string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unidecode` module to convert it to ascii:

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode(u'\u3053\u306e\u30aa')
'konoo'
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't think japanese character can be expressed in ascii. I would like to have the real character

Comment: Off course, sorry for not clarifying it. That is how it would sound phonetically and expressed using latin characters. It depends how you intend to use it. If you need to print the Japanese characters, you can just leave it as it is: `print u'\u3053\u306e\u30aa'` will display `このオ`

Comment: Thanks for your help! So I did try to output "\u3053\u306e\u30aa" in a HTML webpage, but even with m metatag UTF-8 it displays as is, instead of showing the japanese characters. Any idea on how I could decode it?